# How set Set objects (new Set(someArray) iterable by babel plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

.babelrc:
`["@babel/plugin-transform-spread", {"loose": true}],`

code:
`[...new Set([...arr2, ...arr1]),]`

try to:
`...new Set([...sortedPrefixes, ...prefixs]).map((el) => ...),` -
and it can be iterable

Pls tell how can set `[...new Set([...arr2, ...arr1]),]` iterable by babel plugins

Used babel 7

my babels plugins:

```
"plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-spread", {"loose": true}],
    "transform-function-bind",
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    ["lodash"],
    "git-version"
]
```

Comment: I suppose, don't use `{"loose": true}`?

Comment: @Bergi Its true, but then I have a Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance - error (In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method)

Comment: Hm, `Set`s are definitely iterable, are you sure your `arr1` and `arr2` are actual arrays and that `sortedPrefixes` and `prefixs` are iterable as well? What browser are you running the transpiled code in?

Comment: Chrome....So it is array and object: `[...arr1, ...object, ...arr2]`

Comment: You cannot spread an object into an array literal if it doesn't implement the iterable interface. I would assume that this has nothing to do with babel, it doesn't work natively either? Please [edit] your question to include the code as a [mcve]

Comment: This used to work when I use babel-6 and `presets: "stage-0"`...

Comment: Yes this is not a babel, I'm sorry. something added `Symbol.iterator` to my objects,and I can't find what it was